# Polynomial feature expansion in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'd like to do a polynomial feature expansion for a data frame -- for example, a quadratic expansion of a df with (x1, x2, x3) should give a df with (x1, x2, x3, x1^2, x2^2, x3^2, x1x2, x1x3, x2x3). I'm currently using `poly(df$x1, df$x2, df$x3, degree=2, raw=T)` but this requires an unnecessary amount of typing if I have large number of columns. (And `poly(df[,1:20], degree=2, raw=T)` doesn't work.) What's the best way to do this?

Edit: I have too many columns for `poly` (`vector is too large` error). Got it to work with a simple `for` loop:

```
polyexp = function(df){
  df.polyexp = df
  colnames = colnames(df)
  for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
    for (j in i:ncol(df)){
      colnames = c(colnames, paste0(names(df)[i],'.',names(df)[j]))
      df.polyexp = cbind(df.polyexp, df[,i]*df[,j])
    }
  }
  names(df.polyexp) = colnames
  return(df.polyexp)
}
```

Just add additional loops to compute higher-order terms.

Comment: `poly(as.matrix(df[,1:20]) ,degree=2, raw=TRUE)`

Answer (score 5):

You could do this with `do.call`:

```
do.call(poly, c(lapply(1:20, function(x) dat[,x]), degree=2, raw=T))
```

Basically `do.call` takes as the first argument the function to be called (`poly` in your case) and as a second argument a list. Each element of this list is then passed as an argument to your function. Here we make a list containing all of the columns you want to process (I've used `lapply` to get that list without too much typing) followed by the two additional arguments you want to pass.

To see it working on a simple example:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=1:5, z=2:6)
do.call(poly, c(lapply(1:3, function(x) dat[,x]), degree=2, raw=T))
#      1.0.0 2.0.0 0.1.0 1.1.0 0.2.0 0.0.1 1.0.1 0.1.1 0.0.2
# [1,]     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2     4
# [2,]     2     4     2     4     4     3     6     6     9
# [3,]     3     9     3     9     9     4    12    12    16
# [4,]     4    16     4    16    16     5    20    20    25
# [5,]     5    25     5    25    25     6    30    30    36
# attr(,"degree")
# [1] 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2
```

Comment: This gives `Error in rep.int(rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)), orep) : 
  vector is too large` (I actually have 36 columns)

Comment: Did you try actually typing in all 36 columns and seeing if it worked? You may just be trying to generate too large of an object for your computer's memory -- my guess is you will get the same error if you typed all 36 columns.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting the same error... the resulting dataframe should only be 140x702 though.

Comment: @sirallen OK, well then that sounds like a separate question ("vector is too large" error with large calls to poly) as opposed to the current question (how do I make large calls to poly without typing all the vectors). I would suggest you post it as a separate question here on SO with a sample dataset so others can reproduce your issue.

Comment: I went with a for loop in place of `poly`... works fine

Answer (score -1):

That's faster:

```
library(data.table)

###fast version of expand.grid 
expgr   = function(seq1,seq2){
cbind(rep.int(seq1, length(seq2)),c(t(matrix(rep.int(seq2,     length(seq1)), nrow=length(seq2)))))
}

###polynomial feature expansion
polyexp = function(x){
comb    = expgr(1:ncol(x),1:ncol(x))
comb    = comb[comb[,1]!=comb[,2],]
nn      = sapply(1:nrow(comb),function(y){paste(names(x)[comb[y,1]],names(x)[comb[y,2]],sep=".")})
res     = data.table(do.call("cbind",sapply(1:nrow(comb),function(y){x[,comb[y,1],with=F]*x[,comb[y,2],with=F]})))
setnames(res,nn)
}
```

Comment: you could even parallelize it, but i guess that's not necessary